# Reduce array of dicts based on key which is a dict

Tags: python, json, group-by, aggregate, jq

I'm looking for a jq expression that can reduce the json by  grouping them on "labels".I want the output to have a list of targets that share the same labels.

I tried using some combinations of group_by and reduce but wasn't able to get what I wanted.

INPUT:

```
[{
      "targets": [
        "host1"
      ],
      "labels": {
        "platform": "VMware",
        "os": "Windows",
        "datacenter": "dc1",
        "environment": "Production"
      }
    },{
      "targets": [
        "host2"
      ],
      "labels": {
        "platform": "VMware",
        "os": "Windows",
        "datacenter": "dc1",
        "environment": "Production"
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": [
             "host3"
      ],
      "labels": {
        "platform": "VMware",
        "os": "Windows",
        "datacenter": "dc2",
        "environment": "Production"
      }
    }
]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{
      "targets": [
        "host1",
        "host2"
      ],
      "labels": {
        "platform": "VMware",
        "os": "Windows",
        "datacenter": "dc1",
        "environment": "Production"
      }
    },
{
      "targets": [
        "host3",
      ],
      "labels": {
        "platform": "VMware",
        "os": "Windows",
        "datacenter": "dc2",
        "environment": "Production"
      }
    }
]
```

P.S The sample input doesn't have all the keys in "labels" and that list can vary .

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Post the attempts, that you have said you have attempted by `group_by and reduce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if your requirements were clearer, and in particular if your example satisfied the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines.  The following query does, however, meet one interpretation of your specification:

```
group_by(.labels)
| map( { labels: (.[0].labels),
         targets: (map(.targets)|add)} )
```